# How can I make sure my iPhone blocks SMS spam when I ask it to?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, spam

I have an iPhone SE 2 (iOS 15.5).

I keep getting obviously spam texts from the same sender; they look like this:

[image: Spam Text]

As can be seen, the sender is clearly obvious - `FreeStuff`. They appear to be conventional texts (SMS), not iMessages.

Touching on the sender name, I then touch on the 'info' icon, and touch 'Block this Caller', and select 'Block Contact'. That seems to work. However, if I navigate out of this menu, and repeat the process, it appears not to be blocked. Indeed, I am still recieving the spam texts, despite the attempt at blocking.

I've also reported them to my network provider (`7726` in the UK), but of course, I assume that's only as effective as their network-side blocking. I would like to do the blocking on my phone.

Comment: Is the unknown sender filter not working after you set it up and restart the device? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229 [that is different than a device block](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367932/5472)